# How (if at all) should I encapsulate an access token on client side?

Tags: api, authentication, access-token, encapsulation

I'm starting a new project which will have to manage many access tokens for many different APIs. So I was wondering if it was good practice to provide the access tokens to the different classes implementing the API calls or if the tokens should be better encapsulated.

Currently, I see two options:

- every API class constructs their own requests (mostly HTTPS requests), gets the access token from an authentication interface and adds that token to the request in a manner required for that API
- the authentication interface accepts the request from the API class and adds the token to it before actually dispatching the request.

With the latter option, the API class would never see the token, but it would be difficult to foresee all the options how to add the token to the request (header, GET parameter, or totally different ways).

What should be best practice in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Generally an access token contains information such as "is this user privileged" and other authorization-related claims that go beyond authentication.

That means that the authentication service alone cannot deal with these claims, and the API class needs to be able to see them.

Therefore, your API classes should have the opportunity to add claims to the access token. Whether or not they are the ones constructing the token itself is not important.